# Creating a semi ellipse in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scoping

I'm trying to draw a depiction of a partial earth orbit using `tikz`. I want to draw the orbit such that it begins on one side of the globe and wraps around to the other side, nearly completing an ellipse.

My first instinct was to do it manually by plotting several full ellipses and blocking out segments of them using `scope`. However, there's no easy way to get the endpoints to line up nicely without altering the shape of the curve.

I'm obviously a terrible artist which is why I'm doing this in tikz, but desired output should look something like:

[image]

Is there a way to create a more attractive semi-ellipse?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta,intersections,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\muu{0.005}
  \def\R{2.75}
\node[inner sep=0pt] (globe) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{globe.jpg}}; 
\begin{scope}
    \clip (1.05,1.5) rectangle (5,-5);
    \draw [thick, ->] (0,0) ellipse ({(1-\muu)*1.5*\R} and {(1-\muu)*.5*\R}); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Please note that others do not have your graphics file, so I just draw a circle of that radius. Other than that you only need to draw a rotated arc and some `to[out=...,in=...]` stretches. For your convenience I stored the various distances in some macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Rglobe{.125\textwidth}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Halo{1mm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\SmallArc{1ex}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\Rx{0.2\textwidth}
  \draw (0,0) circle[radius=\Rglobe pt];
  \draw[rotate=30] (90:{(\Rglobe+\Halo)*1pt)}) 
  to[out=90,in=180] ++(\SmallArc pt,\SmallArc pt)
  arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,x radius=\Rx pt,
      y radius={(\Rglobe+\Halo+\SmallArc)*1pt}] to[out=180,in=-90] 
    ++(-\SmallArc pt,\SmallArc pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool solution! Thanks for explaining.